# Question about duality of connections in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, connections, information-geometry

Let $S$ be a manifold on which there is given a Riemannian metric $g=\left\langle\ \,,\ \right\rangle$ and two affine connections $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$. If for all vector field $X,Y,Z$ of $S$
$$Z\left\langle X,Y\right\rangle=\left\langle\nabla_{Z}X,Y\right\rangle+\left\langle X,\nabla_{Z}^{*}Y\right\rangle$$ holds then we say that $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ are duals of each other with respect to $g$.

It is given that if a connection $\nabla'$ has the same torsion as $\nabla^*$ and if $\frac{\nabla+\nabla'}{2}$ is metric connection then $\nabla^*=\nabla'$. Someone, please give hint on how to approach this one. Thanks.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the statement: can you point to a reference for this?

Comment: it is from "Methods of information geometry by shun-ichi-amari" chapter 3 (3.1)

Comment: The book says $\underline{\nabla'=\nabla^*}$, not $\nabla=\nabla'$. Is it helpful?

Comment: o yes,thanks for pointing out,can you explain how to prove it.

Comment: Do you want a hint or a solution?

Comment: first, give hint only, I will try by myself. If I find it difficult then I will ask for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hint: the fundamental result in Riemannian Geometry is that for every Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ there is a unique *torsion-free* metric connection. This is usually shown in textbooks by using the Koszul formula, see the section titled "Invariant formulation" in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry).

A slightly less known fact is that for every Riemannian manifold *and every vector-valued $2$-form $T$*, there is a **unique** metric connection having $T$ as torsion. This can be seen from the proof of the Koszul formula, not using the identity $\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX=[X,Y]$ but rather $\nabla_XY-\nabla_YX=[X,Y]+T(X,Y)$.

So, let's get to the proof. Consider the two connections $D':=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla+\nabla')$ and $D^*:=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla+\nabla^*)$. As $\nabla$ and $\nabla^*$ are dual, $D^*$ is a metric connection (exercise for you!). Also, our hypothesis is that $D'$ is a metric connection.

Since $\nabla^*$ and $\nabla'$ have the same torsion, also $D^*$ and $D'$ have the same torsion. But they are also both metric, so $D^*=D'$ by the remark in the second paragraph, and this clearly implies $\nabla^*=\nabla'$.

Comment: okay let me try to solve .

Comment: Hii, Actually I am facing problems while proving it, can you please provide the solution if possible, Thanks.

Comment: @Andyale I have written some more details of the proof. I'm still leaving something for you as an exercise, though!